# Python find words in the string between “#”

Tags: python

I want to search and replace words between the two `#` marks.

The text is random (users add it).

```
example = 'hello this #word1# a it #word2# thanks!'

text = "hello this #word1# a it #word2# thanks!"
```

I need to cut the two words between `#` (word1 and word2) and replace the first letter with uppercase - `.title()`.

I have a code:

```
import re

text = 'hello this #word1# a it #word2# thanks!'
print re.sub('#(\w+)#', lambda m:m.group(1).title(), text)
```

Output: `hello this Word1 a it Word2 thanks!`

How to do that Output: `hello this #Word1# a it #Word2# thanks!`

Comment: `lambda m: "#"+m.group(1).title()+"#"`. Looks like you do not understand what are you doing and why is it working as such. Please invest some time into researching the basics of the language you are using.

Comment: @J0HN while this returns the expected answer for this particular case, it has a design drawback: function and regex are coupled and have to change together. That breaks code connascense when the logic and constant are defined separately.

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this?

```
>>> print re.sub('(#\w+#)', lambda m:m.group(1).title(), text)
hello this #Word1# a it #Word2# thanks!
```

Comment: That code is correct. Which version of Python are you using?

`group(0)` refers to the entire matched string, `group(1)` is for the match inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertions:

```
>>> re.sub('(?<=#)(\w+)(?=#)', lambda m:m.group(1).title(), text)
hello this #Word1# a it #Word2# thanks!
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the `#` to the function.

```
import re

text = 'hello this #word1# a it #word2# thanks!'
print re.sub('#(\w+)#', lambda m: "#" + m.group(1).title() + "#", text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use group(0) instead of group(1)

```
import re

text = 'hello this #word1# a it #word2# thanks!'
print re.sub('#(\w+)#', lambda m:m.group(0).title(), text)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just extend the group, so, it includes the '#' chars:

```
print re.sub('(#\w+#)', lambda m:m.group(1).title(), text)
```